# How to order a data.drame with the variables' order in codebook

Tags: r

If I have a data.frame that contain the variables that listed in df$Var. Is it a way for me to reorder my data col in the order of df$Var?

The df is looks like this:

[image]

Is it a way I can sort dt so the col in dt will in the order of var in df?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `factor` with `levels` specified as the values in 'df1$Var'

```
dt1[order(factor(names(dt1), levels = df1$Var))]
```

Or use `match`

```
dt1[order(match(names(dt1), df1$Var))]
```

Comment: the dt need to be ordered with the same order that variable appears in df. The real variables in df are a lot. not always with the same name+ number.

Comment: @Stataq Can you check my update.  Are you ordering the columns of dt1

Comment: Wonderful. The second part can order the data in the way I want. :D

Comment: after I think through the first method, I finally understand why you use `factor...`. Very clever way. :)